# How can I match a random texture with another texture for animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I have a ball for which I have different colors. The ball has two textures(texture1 and texture2) that I run to do an animation on them. I have different colored balls. Once I call a random function to call any random ball(texture1), my other function doesn't match it with the same ball color(texture2). For instance, if my `texture1` calls redBallUp, my other function doesn't match it with `redballDown`, but randomly calls a texture. Sometimes, it matches it up, but the animation keeps switching between different textures, and sometimes, it doesn't call texture2 at all.

Here's how I set it up:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     let ballTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: getRandomBallUp())
     ballTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
     let ballTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: getRandomBalldDown())
     ballTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    let anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([ballTexture1, ballTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.15)
    let upDown = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)

    ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture1)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.8, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    ball.runAction(upDown)

    self.addChild(ball)
    }

func getRandomBallUp() -> String{
    let randomval = arc4random_uniform(6)
    var ballUp = ""
    switch(randomval)
    {
    case 0:
        ballUp = "BlueBallUp"
    case 1:
        ballUp = "DarkBlueBallUp"
    case 2:
        ballUp = "GreenBallUp"
    case 3:
        ballUp = "PurpleBallUp"
    case 4:
        ballUp = "RedBallUp"
    case 5:
        ballUp = "YellowBallUp"
    default:()
    }
    return ballUp
}

func getRandomBallDown() -> String{
    var ballDown = ""
    if (getRandomBallUp() == "BlueBallUp") {
        ballDown = "BlueBallDown"
    }
    if (getRandomBallUp() == "DarkBlueBallUp") {
        ballDown = "DarkBlueBallDown"
    }
    if (getRandomBallUp() == "GreenBallUp") {
        ballDown = "GreenBallDown"
    }
    if (getRandomBallUp() == "PurpleBallUp") {
        ballDown = "PurpleBallDown"
    }
    if (getRandomBallUp() == "RedBallUp") {
        ballDown = "RedBallDown"
    }
    else if (getRandomBallUp() == "YellowBallUp") {
        ballDown = "YellowBallDown"
    }
    return ballDown
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call getRandomBallUp() you are generating a random value and returning a string based on that value. To avoid this, uou need to change your `getRandomBallDown()` to something like:

```
func getCorrespondingRandomBallDown(ballUp:String) -> String{
    var ballDown = ""
    if (ballUp == "BlueBallUp") {
        ballDown = "BlueBallDown"
    }
    if (ballUp == "DarkBlueBallUp") {
        ballDown = "DarkBlueBallDown"
    }
    if (getRandomBallUp() == "GreenBallUp") {
        ballDown = "GreenBallDown"
    }
    if (ballUp == "PurpleBallUp") {
        ballDown = "PurpleBallDown"
    }
    if (ballUp == "RedBallUp") {
        ballDown = "RedBallDown"
    }
    else if (ballUp == "YellowBallUp") {
        ballDown = "YellowBallDown"
    }
    return ballDown
}
```

You need to also change your didMoveToView:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     let ballUp = getRandomBallUp()
     let ballTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: ballUp)
     ballTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
     let ballTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: getCorrespondingRandomBallDown(ballUp)
     ballTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    let anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([ballTexture1, ballTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.15)
    let upDown = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)

    ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture1)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.8, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    ball.runAction(upDown)

    self.addChild(ball)
    }
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

beyowulf has the answer, but this is swift baby,  lets use some of its features:

```
func getRandomBall() -> (up:String,down:String){
    let randomval = arc4random_uniform(6)
    var ball = ""
    switch(randomval)
    {
    case 0:
        ball = "BlueBall"
    case 1:
        ball = "DarkBlueBall"
    case 2:
        ball = "GreenBall"
    case 3:
        ball = "PurpleBall"
    case 4:
        ball = "RedBall"
    case 5:
        ball = "YellowBall"
    default:()
    }
    return (up:"\(ball)Up",down:"\(ball)Down")
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     let ballTextureName = getRandomBall()
     let ballTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: ballTextureName.up)
     ballTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
     let ballTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: ballTextureName.down)
     ballTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    let anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([ballTexture1, ballTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.15)
    let upDown = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)

    ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture1)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.8, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    ball.runAction(upDown)

    self.addChild(ball)
}
```